# Difference between AddRole and AddRoleDef in SharePoint usergroup.asmx?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

The SharePoint web service usergroup.asmx has two methods to add role definitions to a site collection:

- [AddRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772714.aspx)
- [AddRoleDef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774640.aspx)

Both have the exact same description: "Adds a role definition to the current site collection."

Does anybody know if there is a difference between the two?  So far, the only difference I see is that AddRoleDef takes a 64 bit unsigned integer as one of the parameters, and AddRole takes a 32 bit unsigned integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there, I work for Microsoft and am the PM responsible for permissions management UI in SharePoint vNext.

An *'SPGroup'* is a 'Group' in the UI - a logical group of users or directory groups

[SPGroup on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroup.aspx)

A 'role' is an obsolete term for a 'Permission Level' in the UI

[SPRole on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sprole.aspx)

A 'role definition' is a 'Permission Level' in the UI - a set of 'permissions' ('rights' programatically) that can be thought of as specific base actions a user can perform eg. add item. Authorization is done against a user's having been granted these permissions.

[SPRoleDefinition on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sproledefinition.aspx)

History: In SharePoint v2 we had users / directory groups assigned roles (sets of permissions). In SharePoint v3 we introduced SharePoint groups,

Comment: @Kevin--I did a test and called the AddRole and AddRoleDef methods. Both added new Permission Levels to my site.  There is an AddGroup method in usergroup.asmx which I assume adds what is called a Group in the UI. This seems to be a little different than what your answer suggests.  Maybe this is just an inconsistency between the web service API and the SharePoint object model.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here, but maybe Microsoft plans on adding more rights and that would require more than a 32 bit integer to hold the permissions mask; hence the addition of the same method with a 64 bit integer.